# Images on Wordpress site don't load always

Tags: wordpress

I am working on a Wordpress site and I have uploaded images to be posted on its webpage. Sometimes the images load on the webpage but sometimes they don't. I have tried Chrome, Firefox, Safari and IE and I get the same result. 
Here is the site I am working on. http://www.mreco.org/booking/

I would really appreciate it if someone can help me with this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your main page is over 10 MB, it's way to much, make it lighter and will be loading fine.

Comment: My main page works fine. It's http://mreco.org/booking that doesn't load the images always.

Comment: check mreco-w-kids.jpg, zero-cost.jpg, more-about-pifp.jpg in test they got "The request got a 4XX, 5XX response or couldn’t be loaded" the problem is with those files. Try overwrite them.

Comment: I have re uploaded the files and still getting the same result. Sometimes they load, sometimes they don't.

Comment: You have to dig in server logs (or ask your provider), now image http://www.mreco.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/more-about-pifp.jpg is returning 404 (in more then 33% hits)

Comment: Oh, I just deleted the images and uploaded it back. Still getting the same results though.

Answer (score 0):

May be it's your server problem. Sometimes because of the server problem image doesn't load properly and sometimes it does. It should be better if you transfer your site to another server or turn your pc to a server then try. After the completion of the work then transfer it to a better server. This will help you to get rid of your problem.